# delete everything from output which is behind ":"

Tags: python, linux

when python gives me an output in form like:

```
randomfilename.txt:randomstringmniaonovinaio
```

How can i make from it just

```
randomfilename.txt
```

in python/shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> s = "randomfilename.txt:dslfkjsdosdfu"
>>> print s.split(":")[0]
randomfilename.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> 'randomfilename.txt:randomstringmniaonovinaio'.split(':')[0]
'randomfilename.txt'
```

Answer (score 1):

In the shell you can use `cut`:

```
python yourscript.py | cut --delim=":" -f 1
```

Only the string before the first `:` will be printed. If you do not want to get those lines without `:`, in case such lines appear in your program, you can also add `-s` to the command.

Answer (score 0):

The split method is inefficient if you're doing it frequently, in which case it might be better to use:

```
>>> s='randomfilename.txt:randomstringmniaonovinaio'
>>> s[:s.find(':')]
'randomfilename.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

The other users have given the Python answers.  If, for whatever reason, you wanted to do it with Unix utilities, I think you could just go for:

```
randomFileName=`echo $yourString | sed 's/^\(.*\.txt\):.*/\1/'`
```

That's just a sed substitution operation.

The bit in escaped brackets just matches any set of characters which ends in .txt and stores it in a buffer.  The next bit matches a colon and any text after it.  The `^` means to match from the start of `$yourString`.

The `\1` then replaces everything it matched with whatever is in the first pattern buffer.  In this case, it should be your random file name.